# Filter combo box to show specific data

Tags: ms-access

At the login form, I used DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "Department = 'Finance'"
to restrict user view on the main form so that if the ID and password
match with the Finance department, the form will only preview the data 
from of Finace department's staff. I also put the combo box,FindNextRecord
and FindPreviousRecord to make it become more user friendly. However, the 
combo box doesn't filter the name and show the list of every staff from
different department. Is there is any way to filter the combo box so that
it will only show the staff name from the Finance department

note: Every details of each staff are recorded in a single table.

Comment: What have you done so far for the combo box that has the staff list name? What fields are available?  I feel like you haven't provided useful information that anyone can really help.

Comment: Add a bit more information like the RowSource of the ComboBox. Table design etc.

Comment: Is there a table that has a list of departments? And is the primary key of that table a foreign key in some employee table?

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the reply. the RowSource of the ComboBox is SELECT [Full Database].[Name] FROM [Full Database]; Basically I create a table (Full Database) which consist staff id, name, department and etc. My problem is my current ComboBox shows every staff name from all department. I want the ComboBox to show the staff name from finance department

Comment: Well you can always change the rowsource to `SELECT Name FROM [Full Database] WHERE Department='Finance'` but that's not very dynamic. However you are determining that someone should only see the Finance department is the same criteria for determining what department should be filtered for in the rowsource for the combobox.